# Get role name for admin user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have table for admin user and its roles with their relations. I want admin user listing with their respective role.

I tried below query

```
$adminusers = Admin::whereHas('roles', function($q)
        {
            $q->where('roles.name', '<>', 'Superadmin');
            $q->select('roles.name as roles');
        })->select('id', 'name')->where('admins.status', 'A')->where('admins.is_delete', '0')->paginate(15);
```

but i am not able to retrieve role name from it.

So how can i get the role name from above query?

Answer (score 1):

You can't select from a whereHas closure.  whereHas in this scenario is used to limit the results of admins, not to retrieve the roles.

You can query a relationship of a specific model like so:

```
$singleAdmin->roles()->where('roles.name', '<>', 'Superadmin')->get();
```

Or you can put constraints during eager loading:

```
Admin:::with(['roles' => function ($query) {
    $q->where('roles.name', '<>', 'Superadmin');
}])->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Once eager loaded, you would need to access the collection of roles from `$singleAdmin->roles`.

In some cases, it makes sense to just use a join.

Comment: P.S.  If roles is belongsTo, then `$singleAdmin->roles` will be a model, not a collection and `roles` would be a misleading name for the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the leftJoin method.

```
`$admins = Admin::leftJoin('roles','admin.role_id','=','roles.id')
->select('id', 'name')
->where('admins.status', 'A')
->where('admins.is_delete', '0')
->paginate(15)`
```

Or you can do it in model file

```
`public function role()
{
    return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\Roles::class, 'id', 'role_id');
}`
```